# Rendering html snippet in view based on model property value

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How do I add custom HTML in a View, based on property value of a Model?

For example, my model has a string property "MyType" which can have values "ABC", "DEF", or "GHI".

Then, in the view, I'd like to output a large amount of HTML, specific to the individual "MyType" that is passed with the Model.

I know within the view I could have a helper function, which looks at Model.MyType and has a switch statement to display some HTML, but is there a more elegant way to do this, to abstract away the HTML from the View?

Even if I could create a helper function which would have a switch, but then call off to a cshtml file to get the appropriate HTML.  I'm thinking kind of like how DisplayTemplates work, but I can't really use those, as that means it will be called for every STRING, not my Model-specific property...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first you can use display templates as long as you decorate your property with the `[UIHint("Foo")]` annotation. The "Foo" portion corresponds to a specific display template, so you can use different ones for different types of strings.

However, partials are probably your best bet here. You can put the bit of HTML for each `MyType` value into a partial by the same name. Then you can just call:

```
@Html.Partial(Model.MyType)
```

In other words, you pass the type directly as the name of the partial to use. Just be careful that the values always correspond to partials that exist in your project, or you'll start to get exceptions. If someone decides to add another value for `MyType`, and neglects to add the associated partial, your app goes boom. You could add a bit of safety, by checking the value against known partials, and only rendering the partial if it's one of those:

```
@if (new[] { "ABC", "DEF", "GHI" }.Contains(Model.MyType))
{
    @Html.Partial(Model.MyType)
}
```

Then, at least, the worst-case scenario is nothing gets rendered.